# VisualVM - not a valid core dump

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm

I have .hprof heap dump generated from JVM OutOfMemory (JDK 1.5 version).

When I try to add this file in VisualVM, it tells me file is not a valid core dump.

However from I'm able to run jhat for this dump file without any issue.

any ideas why ?

Answer (score 16):

The file you are trying to open is a *Head Dump* not a *Core Dump*.

Follow this steps:

1. Go to ***File*** > ***Load...***
2. Select the *File Format:* as ***Heap Dumps (*.hprof, *.*)***
3. Choose your file and click on Open.

Answer (score 6):

Heap dump is not a core dump. So you have to open your .hprof file as a heap dump in VisualVM.